# How do I get rid of git (non-fast-forward) issue

Tags: git

I'm new to Git.

I created a brand new branch on a newly cloned repo. I want to push my work to the develop branch. I have only done 1 commit.

I did my work and did the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git checkout my-branch
git merge develop
git push origin develop
```

But I get the classic error:

```
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:project/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I made sure my branch and develop were up to date - no worries, they are. So I tried again and got the same message.

I then made sure I don't have any other branches.

I'm not sure what else I can do. Would anyone know?

Comment: @matt but there's no where to pull mybranch from. It hasn't been pushed before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current branch is my-branch, not develop. You cannot push from it to develop.

```
git checkout develop
git merge my-branch
git push
```

Comment: Thanks, so how do I make a pull request for my branch?

Comment: You said "I want to push my work to the develop branch." Now you say you want to create a pull request. These goals contradict to each other.

Comment: When you pushed to developed, you cannot create PR, because there is nothing to merge any more.

Comment: yeah, look git makes no sense to me. I've been basing my head against a wall with if for ****ing years and it's still just a black hole of stress. If it were up to me I wouldn't touch it ever again, but I've still got to pay the bills. I want to create a PR so people can view my code and review it. I also want to push the code to develop so it can be tested. I don't know man, it's just ***king hard, I'm trying to learn, I need help, I'm doing my ***king best.

Comment: If you want to create a PR, you should not merge your branch to develop.

Comment: I'd suggest you read about Git flow. It is pretty short. Briefly to your case: You merge develop into your branch (not other way around), then you push **your** branch (not develop), then you create PR, then smb. reviews your PR. If review was successful, **he** (not you) will merge your PR into develop. You should never push to develop.

Comment: yep, I know. That's exaclty what I was trying to do. The thing is - even on a fresh branch on a fresh repo - it just throws a random error. Each time is different.

Comment: See your last command: you are in the my-branch, but you are trying to push to develop. This is not right. You should push to the origin my-branch, i.e. to the remote counterpart of your local my-branch.

Comment: If you have no service such remote branch, git will show you command how you can create it.

Comment: After pushing you go to GUI of your Git (GitLab, GitHub, whatever) and create there a PR from your remote my-branch to the remote develop.

Comment: Then ask for review.

Comment: Thanks @mentallurg. That's very helpful